# Retry GameCenter Authentication

Tags: objective-c, center, gamekit

In my app, the app prompts the user to login to GameCenter right when it opens. If they decline, I'd like to let them have the ability to login once they manually press on a GameCenter button. However, the same code that I use to authenticate them on startup will not open up the authentication view controller any time after startup. Any advice?
I'm using:

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
[localPlayer setAuthenticateHandler:(^(UIViewController* viewcontroller, NSError *error) {
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I've got the same problem.  So far my only solution is a popup telling the user to go login using the GC app, which is kind of lame.

Comment: No, sorry. I had to just check if it couldn't authenticate, then it would show a popup saying something like "Please log in to the Game Center app to use GameCenter."

Answer (score 0):

Its explained in Listing 3-1 "Setting an authentication handler" of the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW19)  (although a little unclearly). Here is what I do:

- If there is no authenticated player, I store the view controller returned by the block, and display it later when the player tries to start a "multiplayer" game. This is better than showing the view controller right away each time the app starts, because some people don't have or want game center accounts, and may not want to create one.
- If authenticated, I enable game center features and then when the player tries to start the game I directly launch the multiplayer (obviously no need to show the controller here).
- If the process failed, then I disable game center features and multiplayer and show a message like you did, to login through the game center app, and offer the option of launching the game center app. .
  The code is almost identical to the code on apples documentation:

---

```
-(void)authenticateLocalPlayer
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    __weak GKLocalPlayer *blockLocalPlayer = localPlayer;

    //Block is called each time GameKit automatically authenticates
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error)
    {
        [self setLastError:error];
        if (viewController)
        {
            self.authenticationViewController = viewController;
            [self disableGameCenter];
        }
        else if (blockLocalPlayer.isAuthenticated)
        {
            [self authenticatedPlayer:blockLocalPlayer];
        }
        else
        {
            [self disableGameCenter];
        }
    };
}
```

`self.authenticationViewController` is `strong`, so I can show it later.